# Samsung Galaxy S3 Camera Intent Landscape

Tags: java, android, galaxy, android-camera-intent

I've searched for 2 days trying to find the answer to my problem and haven't really found a satisfactory answer.

I'm making an app that calls the camera Intent and basically takes the photo captured, put's it into an ImageView to preview, and I have a button to save the file to a user defined folder in an app folder I create.

I can run my app quite easily with the AVD, my GF's Droid Razr M. But when I try to run it on my GS3 it dies a horrible death after hitting accept on the image, unless I force the app to a Landscape mode in the manifest, and keep the phone in landscape when i take the picture. I think it has something to do with what I saw about the onActivityResult data input being null as i get a null pointer exception like they do. I'm looking for a solution specific to my problem.

My Camera Intent:

```
        if (v.getId() == R.id.snap) {
        //start camera up, and set temp file to store image for viewing inside the app
        String identity =  android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        Intent intent1,cameraIntent;
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo1.jpg");
        try {
        if (identity.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung")) {

            intent1 = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), identity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo1.jpg");
            mUri=Uri.fromFile(f);
            intent1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent1, TAKE_PICTURE);
            }
        else {
            cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), identity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo1.jpg");
            mUri=Uri.fromFile(f);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
            }
```

I know that I really don't have to have the Manufacturer part, but the framework is there in case I have to implement a Samsung specific fix.

My save block:

```
else if (v.getId() == R.id.save){
        //store photo in a bitmap, and set string to make folder to store photos later on
        Bitmap bitmap = mPhoto;
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File newDir;

        if (value.isEmpty())
            newDir = new File(root + "/CamExample/default_folder");

        else
            newDir = new File(root + "/" + "CamExample/" + value);

        //if the chosen directory doesn't exist
        if (!newDir.exists()) {
            newDir.mkdirs();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "folder created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //if it does exist
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "directory already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //image naming convention to avoid duplicate images, should look like IMG_yyyMMdd_HHmmss.jpg
        String TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        String photoname = "IMG_"+TIMESTAMP+".jpg";
        File file1=new File (newDir, photoname);

        if (file1.exists()) {
            file1.delete();
        }

        try {
            //actually create the jpeg file and put it in file1 in newDir
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file1);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_holder)).setImageDrawable(null);
            mPhoto=null;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), photoname+" has been saved properly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), photoname+" has not saved properly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And my onActivityResult definition:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {

    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(mUri, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            try {
                mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mUri);
                ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_holder)).setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my logcat:

```
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.camexample/com.example.camexample.Main}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.camexample/com.example.camexample.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2639)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3576)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.camexample/com.example.camexample.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    ... 13 more
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.notifyChange(IContentService.java:452)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:1280)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:1259)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at com.example.camexample.Main.onActivityResult(Main.java:190)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5363)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
08-20 21:58:26.387: E/AndroidRuntime(10541):    ... 14 more
```